# Update column in before update trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to update a column of a SQLITE db depending on its old value and modified new value.
This is what I was trying:

```
    CREATE Trigger if not exists database_yml_content_fixer 
before update of content on table_name
begin     
  NEW.content = case when OLD.content LIKE '%some_string%' then
    'dynamic_yml_configuration:
  setting: some_string
  setting2: other_string
  dynamic_setting: ' || NEW.column_name || '
  dynamic_setting2: ' || NEW.different_column_name || '
  dynamic_setting3: ''http://' || NEW.some_ip || ':' || NEW.some_port || ''''
  else 
  NEW.content
  end
end;
```

When I try to execute this statement I always get this error:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "NEW": syntax error)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The proximate cause of the error is bad syntax. According to the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) `BEGIN` is followed by an update||insert||delete||select stmt. Correcting that will be the beginning of your troubleshooting journey.

Comment: Thanks that helped! I rewrote the trigger to an after update trigger with a when condition enabled. In the begin block I am just updating the row with an update statement again.